# Django - Field validation to ensure the data is a list of tuples of float

Tags: python, django

I have a Charfield where the user must enter a list of tuples of float (without the brackets) like: (0,1),(0.43,54),(24.2,4)

What would be the way to ensure: first that the input is a list of tuples, and second, that tuples are made of float only?

What I tryed so far:

```
def clean_dash_array(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data['dash_array']
    try:
        data_list = eval("[%s]" % data) #transform string into list
        for t in data_list:
            if type(t) != tuple:
                raise forms.ValidationError("If: You must enter tuple(s) of float delimited with coma - Ex: (1,1),(2,2)")
    except:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Except: You must enter tuple(s) of float delimited with coma - Ex: (1,1),(2,2)")
    return data
```

This is not complete because it can't validate that the tuples contain float only.

Edit:

```
def clean_dash_array(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data['dash_array']
    try:
        data_cleaned = [tuple(float(i) for i in el.strip('()').split(',')) for el in data.split('),(')]
    except:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Except: You must enter tuple(s) of int or float delimited with coma - Ex: (1,1),(2,2)")
    return data
```

This clean method seems to work and do not use eval() as suggested by: Iain Shelvington.

Do you think this will validate the data for any kind of erroneous input?

Comment: You should NOT be running eval() on user provided input

Comment: ok thanks for the advice, is it better to use ast.literal_eval ?

Comment: No. Never. Absolutely not. Please never go near those functions for your own sake. You are searching for patterns in a string, use the `re` module instead

Comment: That should work, you are converting the numbers to `int` instead of `float` though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is working:

```
def clean_dash_array(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data['dash_array']
    try:
        data_cleaned = [tuple(float(i) for i in el.strip('()').split(',')) for el in data.split('),(')]
    except:
        raise forms.ValidationError("You must enter tuple(s) of int or float delimited with commas - Ex: (1,1),(2,2)")
    return data
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly this should do it:

```
def clean_dash_array(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data['dash_array']
    for tuple_array in data:
        if type(tuple_array) == tuple:
            for tuple_data in tuple_array:
                if type(tuple_data) == float:
                    #Do something with this
                else:
                    return "Error: Not a float"
        else:
            return "Error: Not a tuple."
```